# Java String Objects

Tags: java, object

I have the following code:

```
public class Porow{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        String s1 = "foo";
        String s2 = "foo";

        System.out.println(s1 == s2);
        System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));

        String s3 = new String ("foo");
        System.out.println(s1 == s3);
        System.out.println(s1.equals(s3));
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
true
true
false
true
```

I am trying to understand and explain what's going on here. And I need some guidance. Will I be right to say s1 and s2 are same objects stored in different parts of memory and that's why we get the first 2 `true`s?

Why is the 3rd output `false`? is s3 a different object? and why does it produce `true` with the `equals` method on s1? I'd appreciate some help. Thanks :).

EDIT: 
This question is not about `==` nor `equals()` I know what they are. My question is more related to memory references and addresses. So don't just presume I'm asking about String Comparison. I'm asking about a whole different thing here.

Comment: I don' think this question is about String comparison, but String object reference comparison

Comment: This link will clear all your doubts. http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/27/string-comparison-with-equals-and-assignment-operator/

Comment: I don't know why people closed this question. It's not a "how do I compare strings" question.

Comment: @peeskillet exactly! this is not the question they are thinking it is. they just read the subject and assume something else cause it' a common quesion. but i mean something completely different here.

Comment: @siaw_23 I saw this exact same type question asked not to too long ago, and it got a bunch of upvotes. No closes for duplicate "How do I compare Strings?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in the 3rd scenario, a new object is created(the `new` keyword creates a new string object) and `==` is used for object reference equality. That's why it returns `false`.

Whereas the `equals()` method is used for String value equality, and hence, it returns `true`.

In the first and second case, the "foo" String literal is [interned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_intern_pool) and thus, both `s1` and `s2` refer the same String literal.

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator checks reference equivalence.  If the two references are equivalent, then they're the same instance.

Your first example works because the strings are interned - but don't rely on this.  `equals()` actually checks to see if the two Strings contain the same data.

With the `new` keyword, a new reference is created for the other string - hence, they no longer point to the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

Because == tests that the strings refer to the same object and equals tests if they are equivalent. Your line

```
String s3 = new String ("foo");
```

constructs a new reference to the constant "foo" String. Take a look at [What is String interning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10578984/2970947) for a bit more, but be aware that interning will use [PermGen space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11009795/2970947).

Answer (score 0):

String are put into a String pool

When you have

```
String s1 = "foo";
String s2 = "foo";
```

Only one "foo" is placed into the String pool.

So

```
s1 == s2 is true becuase they reference the Same String "foo" in the pool
```

To answer your question, your assumptions are right!

The last true `s1.equals(s3)` compares the value "foo", that's why they are equal.

So just remember with Strings

```
== compares Object reference

equals compares value.
```